# Regex matching troubles

Tags: java, regex

I have this input:

```
;Client = tefexx;Test = tgrfdrff;Piemel = thgfress
```

And this regex:

```
(;Client = )
```

The word in the regex would change depending on the needs. But in this case I would want to only return tefexx. I don't understand how to match just that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
(;Client = (.*?);)
```

In your exemple, this regexp's second capturing group will hold 'tefexx' only.

Answer (score 0):

This should work `/Client = ([a-zA-z]+);/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `Pattern` and `Matcher`:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Re {
    static String s = ";Client = tefexx;Test = tgrfdrff;Piemel = thgfress";
    static String re = ";Client = ([^;]*);";

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}


$ java Re
tefexx
```